# What Framework and Header file contain the constant for kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I keep seeing samples that use kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO for the Apple audio unit api.  I am wondering however what framework/header file contains this constant.

Comment: A simple search in the documentation would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO file is in the header AUComponent.h.  It is in the AudioUnit.framework.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, open Xcode and click `Help` menu in the top bar, select `Documentation and API Reference`, search `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO` and you'll see the results.

That's the way to find the sample usage and document for official resource.

Comment: I was unaware of this API reference thanks.  I still after searching for kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO cannot figure out where it says AUComponent.h is the needed header.  Is there some standard place to look this up that I am missing?  It could be something very obvious I am just not used to Objective-C.

Comment: @Benju I usually use sample code results to help me learn how to use a new api. And in the project you can command+click the symbol and see where it is defined.